installing nvidia_cublas_cu12-12.1.3.1-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64 takes forever - installing torch inside docker
I am trying to dockerize a simple streamlit app that also requires pytorch here is my poetry content
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"
watchdog = "^3.0.0"
streamlit = "^1.27.2"
loguru = "^0.7.2"
pre-commit = "^3.5.0"
python-dotenv = "^1.0.0"
omegaconf = "^2.3.0"
sentence-transformers = "2.6.1"
torch = "2.2.2"
numpy = "<2.0"
poetry-plugin-export = "^1.8.0"

when I build the docker and get interactive to its shell; I do poetry install but it gives me
207.4   ConnectionError
207.4 
207.4   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.
207.4 
207.4   at /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/models.py:826 in generate
207.4        822│                     raise ChunkedEncodingError(e)
207.4        823│                 except DecodeError as e:
207.4        824│                     raise ContentDecodingError(e)
207.4        825│                 except ReadTimeoutError as e:
207.4     →  826│                     raise ConnectionError(e)
207.4        827│                 except SSLError as e:
207.4        828│                     raise RequestsSSLError(e)
207.4        829│             else:
207.4        830│                 # Standard file-like object.
207.4 
207.4 Cannot install nvidia-cublas-cu12.
207.4 
208.8 make: *** [Makefile:18: install] Error 1
------
Dockerfile:25
--------------------
  23 |     
  24 |     # install the dependencies
  25 | >>> RUN make install
  26 |     
  27 |     # Expose the port Streamlit runs on
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c make install" did not complete successfully: exit code: 2
make: *** [docker-build] Error 1" I have even set "

it turned out based on the discussion here poetry is too slow; so I extracted the requirement.txt via poetry export -f requirements.txt > requirements.txt python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
then rebuilt the docker, got into the shell and type python -m pip install -r requirements.txt now it returns
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 18.2/18.2 MB 12.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting nvidia-cublas-cu12==12.1.3.1
  Downloading nvidia_cublas_cu12-12.1.3.1-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (410.6 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━╸━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 120.8/410.6 MB 28.7 MB/s eta 0:00:11
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 438, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 561, in read
    data = self._fp_read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 527, in _fp_read
    return self._fp.read(amt) if amt is not None else self._fp.read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 90, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 466, in read
    s = self.fp.read(amt)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/socket.py", line 717, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1307, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1163, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
TimeoutError: The read operation timed out

I even have set the pip's timeout to 500; but it stil get into timeout; in conclusion seems there is something wrong with nvidia_cublas_cu12-12.1.3.1-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
to remind you my goal is to dockerize this app so I am open to any other alternative. I still would like to stick to poetry as my hard requirement.
here is my dockerfile
# Use an official Python base image with Python 3.10.5
FROM python:3.10-slim

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the repository files into the container
COPY . /app

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    make \
    less \
    nano \
    curl \
    build-essential && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set environment variables
ENV POETRY_REQUESTS_TIMEOUT=120

# Install Poetry
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir poetry

# Expose the port Streamlit runs on
EXPOSE 8501

